# Azure iOS push SDK doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

It used to work like a charm, everything was all set, from the certificate to the azure backend.

But from a few days (less than a week), I don't receive push notification anymore.

The workflow is as this on the device :

- I ask apple for my device token
- I get my device token and send it to Azure

But when I send it to azure, I got an error, with the detailed URL request that had the error :

```
URLRequest failed:
2017-03-15 18:27:41.174 Messenger[390:78044] URL:https://XXXX.servicebus.windows.net/messenger-dev/Registrations/XXXXXX-XXXXXX-1?api-version=2013-04
2017-03-15 18:27:41.175 Messenger[390:78044] Headers:{
    Authorization = "SharedAccessSignature sr=http%3a%2f%2fYYYYYYY.servicebus.windows.net%2fXXXXXXXXX%3fapi-version%3d2013-04&sig=XXXXX&se=XXXXX&skn=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature";
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
    "User-Agent" = "NOTIFICATIONHUBS/2013-04(api-origin=IosSdk; os=iPhone OS; os_version=9.2.1;)";
}
2017-03-15 18:27:49.897 Messenger[390:78044] ERROR : URLRequest failed for <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x12895e530> { URL: https://YYYYY.servicebus.windows.net/messenger-dev/Registrations/XXXXX?api-version=2013-04 } with status code: bad request
```

I tried to send this via postman and I got a 404... (401 if I wait to long and a generated token expired).

**Edit**

Here is my code

```
@interface PushManager : NSObject {
    SBNotificationHub *hub;
}

+ (PushManager *) sharedInstance;



@implementation PushManager

+ (PushManager *) sharedInstance {

    static PushManager * instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t token;

    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

- (id) init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING
                                              notificationHubPath:AZURE_NOTIFICATION_PATH];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) enablePushNotificationForTopics:(NSSet<NSString *> *)topicsToEnable
                           addUserId:(BOOL)doAddUser
                             success:(PushManagerSuccessBlock) successBlock
                               error:(PushManagerErrorBlock) errorBlock {
    if ([PushManager isApplicationEnableForPushNotification])
    {
        NSMutableSet<NSString *> *topicsToEnable = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:topicsToEnable];

        [hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:[[MessengerUserDefault sharedInstance] getPushNotificationToken]
                                  tags:topicsToEnable
                            completion:^(NSError* error) {
                                if (error == nil) {
                                    [TopicDBManager enablePushNotificationOnServerForTopics:topicsToEnable];
                                    [[DBClient sharedInstance] saveContext];
                                    successBlock();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"ERROR : %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                                    errorBlock(error);
                                }
                            }];
```

Comment: Can you add your code for how you send the device token to Azure please?  This will aid our understanding of the question.

Comment: I added my code. Therefore, I have app in production that used to work one week ago, there was no update on the app nor on the server side and it's not working now. I checked certificate and I can connect with openssl s_client

Comment: Ok it's working this morning... I run the exact same request just changing the token and got a 200 OK.